# Cannot assign a new enum value to a field of a struct

Tags: rust

I've a `Game` struct

```rust
pub struct Game {
    pub status: Status
}
```

Where `Status` is an Enum

```rust
pub Status {
    Initializing,
    Running,
    End
}
```

I have this code as implementation of game, should be the main loop, oversimplified now only to evidence the issue

```rust
pub fn run(&self) {
    &self.status = Status::ExitGame;
}
```

Compiler is telling I cannot assign to the expression

```
   --> src\game\game.rs:262:22
    |
262 |         &self.status = Status::End;
    |         ------------ ^
    |         |
    |         cannot assign to this expression
```

Could you *explain* me *why* I cannot do this?

Comment: More formally, the left-hand side of an assignment expression must be an [_assignee expression_](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions.html#place-expressions-and-value-expressions). The expression `&self.status` is a value expression that does not represent a memory location, so you can't assign to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot assign to `&self.status`, this is a temporary reference. You can assign to `self.status`, but you'll have to make the method take `&mut self`.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: I accepted as valid the answer from @chayim-friedman. I am only expanding the answer for my self (and hope future googlers)

I modified calling code from

```
fn main() {
    let game = Game::new();
    game.run();
}
```

to

```
fn main() {
    let mut game = Game::new();
    game.run();
}
```

and, as suggested, modified

```
pub fn run(&self) {
    &self.status = Status::ExitGame;
}
```

to

```
pub fn run(&mut self) {
    self.status = Status::ExitGame;
}
```